# Multiplying summation of vectors

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose I have a symmetric matrix $H$ with orthonormal eigenvectors $u_{i}$, hence $Hu_{i}= \lambda_{i}u_{i}$. Now suppose I want to calculate $v^{T}Hv$.

As the eigenvectors span the space, we can write $v$ as a linear combination of the eigenvectors $v=\sum_{i}c_{i}u_{i}$. So:

$v^{T}Hv = (\sum_{i}c_{i}u_{i})^{T}H(\sum_{j}c_{j}u_{i})$

I am not exactly sure how to simplify this expression. I believe one can write:

$H(\sum_{j}c_{j}u_{i}) = \sum_{j}Hc_{j}u_{j} = \sum_{j}c_{j}\lambda_{j}u_{j}$

$v^{T}Hv = (\sum_{i}c_{i}u_{i})^T(\sum_{j}c_{j}\lambda_{j}u_{j})$

But then I am not sure how to obtain:

$v^{T}Hv = \sum_{i}\lambda_{i}c_{i}^2$

How do you calculate the inner product of linear combinations of vectors? Can you multiply each vector independently and then sum the result?

Comment: The transpose of $\sum c_iu_i$ is $\sum c_iu_i^t$. Using the distributive law to multiply the two sums, you get a sum of terms of the form $\lambda_jc_ic_ju_i^tu_j$. The $u_i$ are orthonormal – that tells you what to do with the $u_i^tu_j$. After that, everything falls out. Try it!

Comment: Getting anywhere?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes I think I understand it. We are essentially multiplying two summations and all terms except for $u_{i}^Tu_{j}$ where $i=j$ are 0 as they are orthogonal. That only leaves the terms where $i=j$ and in this case $u_{i}^Tu_{j}=1$. Thanks!

Comment: Good! Let me encourage you to write it up and to post it here as an answer.